# getJSON не работает в codepen

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь получить данные из API Dark Sky, в CodePen, ничего не происходит, вот код:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b2768da01b075c696b987b9265515009/37.8267,-122.4233", function(json) {
        console.log("ok")
        $(".message").html(json);
      });
  });
```

в консоли ok не появляется, в div с классом message тоже ничего не вносится. В чем может быть проблема?

Ссылка https://codepen.io/Maksim25/pen/owypQa?editors=1011